# Black bars on Eclipse after upgrading to Kubuntu 15.10

Tags: kubuntu, themes, eclipse, gtk, plasma-5

I just upgrade my desktop to Kubuntu 15.10 from Kubuntu 15.04, and I bizarre issue started happening in Eclipse. Looks like the divisors on software are black bars, instead of the desktop color for some reason. Below you can see two images with examples of that. As for configurations I'm using?

**Workspace Theme**: Breeze
**Desktop Theme**: Air
**Widget Style**: Breeze
**Windows Decoration**: air-breeze

**GTK2 theme**: oxygen-gtk
**GTK3 theme**: oxygen-gtk

Icon theme: Breeze

[image: Black bar on icons]
[image: Black bar on menu]

Comment: Does this only show-up in eclipse?

Comment: Of the applications I'm running right now it is the only one I saw it happen. And It happen only after the 15.10 upgrade.

Comment: I can confirm this, it happens in Meld to me.

Comment: I managed to remove it by changing the GTK3 theme I use. I downloaded the Next-Aurora theme and used it. It does look ok, although it is not perfect. So I think that the issue lies on the oxygen-gtk theme. Something is either missing or wrong